# Jackson: Deserializing a polymorphic list

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I would like to implement a custom deserializer for our REST API that is not only used by Java application. Therefore I don't want to have Jackson putting type information into the serialized JSON.

I'm currently struggling with deserializing `CollectionExpand` since it contains a list `data` of specific `ResourceModel`.

```java
public class EntityModel<R extends ResourceModel> implements Serializable {

  private R data;
  private List<ResourceLink> links;
  private List<CollectionExpand> expands;
}

public class CollectionExpand {

  private String name;
  // Resource Model is an interface
  private Collection<ResourceModel> data;
}
```

`ResourceModel` is an interface an each `CollectionExpand` contains a collection of one type of `ResourceModel` per `name`.

For example a json output could look like this.

```json
{
    "data": {},
    "links": [],
    "expand": [
        {
            "name": "photos",
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "hello.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "hello.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "persons",
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 783378,
                    "name": "Peter",
                    "age": 12
                },
                {
                    "id": 273872,
                    "name": "Maria",
                    "age": 77
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see each name contains the same type of resource model. `photos` contains `PhotoResourceModel` and `person` contains `PersonResourceModel`.

I started to implement my custom Jackson Deserializer

```java
public class CollectionExpandDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<CollectionExpand> {

  public CollectionExpandDeserializer() {
    super(CollectionExpand.class);
  }

  @Override
  public CollectionExpand deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    CollectionExpand collectionExpand = new CollectionExpand();

    if (Objects.equals(p.nextFieldName(), "name")) {
      collectionExpand.setName(p.nextTextValue());
    }

    if (Objects.equals(p.nextFieldName(), "data")) {
       // depending on the field name I would like to delegate the deserialization to a specific type.


       if (name.equals("photos") {
         // how to do this?
         collectionExpand.setData(/* deserialize to a list of PhotoResource */);
       }

    }


    return collectionExpand;
  }
```

I'm current stuck on how can I delegate telling Jackson to deserialize this as a `PhotoResource` list.

In general is this the right approach or is there another way to do it (without putting any Jackson meta data into the JSON while serialization)?

Comment: I had a similar struggle with my project I'm doing which uses C#. Another workaround you could use (I know it is cringeworthy but it works) is to define a custom type which stores each concrete type as a separate collection and you can define mapper methods which let you convert between the two forms. This method relies on type matching.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari thank you for your comment. The thing is I need to deserialize the data back into the existing class. No chance on changing the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up implementing my custom deserializer as below

```java
@Override
public CollectionExpand deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {

    JsonNode node = ctx.readTree(p);

    CollectionExpand collectionExpand = new CollectionExpand();

    collectionExpand.setName(node.get("name").asText());

    ArrayNode data = node.withArray("data");

    Iterator<JsonNode> iterator = data.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

      Class<? extends ResourceModel> aClass = resolveClass(collectionExpand.getName());

      if (aClass != null) {
        JsonNode jsonNode = iterator.next();
        collectionExpand.getData().add(p.getCodec().treeToValue(jsonNode, aClass));
      }
    }
    return collectionExpand;
}

private Class<? extends ResourceModel> resolveClass(String name) {
    if ("contents".equals(name)) {
      return ContentsGetResourceModel.class;
    } else if ("tags".equals(name)) {
      return TagsGetResourceModel.class;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
}
```

I took my a while to understand how to deserialize a `JsonNode`/`TreeNode` into a specific type. In the end I learned that this can be basically done by using the parsers codec.

```java
PhotoResource photoResource = p.getCodec().treeToValue(jsonNode, PhotoResource.class);
```